# Linux socket - set non blocking using O_NONBLOCK

Tags: sockets, network-programming, ipc

If I make a TCP socket descriptor non blocking using `fcntl(sockfd, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);`, does that make all the subsequent socket API's like `read()/listen()/accept()/ etc..` also non blocking?

Comment: Making these socket API calls non-blocking is exactly the point of O_NONBLOCK. What else did you assume O_NONBLOCK does?

Comment: @user207421
, @Steffen Ullrich
Thanks. Well, I was wondering when I saw a code which does O_NONBLOCK and later use ```recv(sd, buffer, size, MSG_DONTWAIT)```. I got this question thinking, if the programmer was trying to address some corner cases.

Comment: Let's just say he was using a 'belt-and-braces' approach ;-) `MSG_DONTWAIT` is for the case when you *haven't* set `O_NONBLOCK` and you want a non-blocking just for that `recv() alone. Hard to see the point frankly, I've never used it in 40 years.

Answer (score 2):

There's an official answer in a man page, specifically [socket(7)](https://linux.die.net/man/7/socket):

> It is possible to do nonblocking I/O on sockets by setting the O_NONBLOCK flag on a socket file descriptor using fcntl(2). Then all operations that would block will (usually) return with EAGAIN (operation should be retried later); connect(2) will return EINPROGRESS error. The user can then wait for various events via poll(2) or select(2).

So yes, setting `O_NONBLOCK` will cause blocking operations to return EAGAIN/EINPROGRESS instead of blocking.